# Не удалось найти часть пути wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь получить информацию из файла и вывести ее на экран, однако вылезает ошибка не удаётся "Не удалось найти часть пути". Всё перепроверил, всё правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего может появляться эта ошибка? Только изучаю эту тему поэтому очень прошу помочь, буду очень благодарен.
Вот мой код:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MshpHW1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MshpHW1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="725">
    <Grid>
        <Label  Margin="30,70,282,319" FontSize="25">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left">Для работы автомата <LineBreak/>требуется загрузить меню</TextBlock>
        </Label>
        <Button x:Name="Upload" Content="Загрузить" Width="120" Height="80" Margin="280 -280 -150 0" Click="Upload_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="Menu1" Width="150" Height="40" Margin="-400 90 0 0"/>
        <Button x:Name="Menu2" Width="150" Height="40" Margin="0 90 -200 0"/>
        <Button x:Name="Do" Content="D o" Width="150" Height="180" Margin="-400 350 0 0"/>
        <Image x:Name="Coffee" Width="150" Height="180" Margin="384,350,183,-11"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

c#:

```
 public partial class MainWindow
    {

        private string[] Arr { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)| *.txt";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName, UriKind.Absolute);
                Arr = File.ReadAllLines(uri.AbsolutePath);

                foreach (string s in Arr)
                {
                    Menu1.Content += s + "\n";
                }     
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName);`?

Comment: спасибо, выручил